# Handling mouse events on a text label (NSText)

Tags: c#, cocoa, events, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm a Xamarin and Cocoa newbie :)

I need to handle mouse events like mouseover or click for a label (like NSText, right?), as for other controls.

I noticed WinForms-like event handling is possible only for certain events (like "Activated" for a NSButton), but I need to handle more events.

Looking for best practices in xamarin developer area, I read this page http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events and then tried to subclass NSText and override methods like MouseEntered, but I get the following error message:

*All NSText methods must be implemented by subclassers. They should not call super.*

What to do?

**UPDATE**: For custom events, should be used NSTextView and not NSText, as written here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: is this a Mac or an iOS app?

Comment: Mac App (mac cocoa controls have NS as class prefix).

Comment: Right, but the link you included is to the iOS docs.

Comment: You're right, but mac section in xamarin docs is nearly empty. That link was the only I was able to find there.